# Pyinstaller giving ModuleNotFoundError when importing sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyinstaller, executable

I'm converting a python script into an executable file with pyinstaller. I create the .exe file successfully, but when I run it (in windows), cmd returns the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
[16964] Failed to execute script scriptname

Sqlalchemy is the last module imported in the script (cx_Oracle, pandas, other internal modules import successfully). Sqlalchemy is stored in the same directories as my other modules.

Other sources suggested importing sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator or trying to put sqlalchemy module in as a hidden import argument. I tried adding both sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator as hidden import arguments on different attempts but neither fixed the issue.

i.e. pyinstaller --onefile scriptname.py --hiddenimports=sqlalchemy

I also read the xref-scriptname html document in the build folder that pyinstaller creates to try to figure out why sqlalchemy wasn't importing but couldn't figure it out.

Any suggestions on how to get this executable to import sqlalchemy would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: ANSWER
I figured out a work around if anyone has this issue in the future: I built the executable program without the --onefile argument.      ie: pyinstaller scriptname.py.    This built an executable .exe file within a folder with everything necessary to run the file, instead of having everything compiled into 1 file. I then copied and pasted my sqlalchemy module folder from site_packages into my pyinstaller dist folder. This worked - the .exe program finds sqlalchemy locally when a user runs this program now